# Request WinForm Label Value from Background Worker illegal?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am wondering if the following will affect the performance of my application.

Every call I make to update the background worker I do the right way without cross threading, but if I request a value from the UserInterface and not update it, is this illegal and could it affect the performance?

Here is a small snippet from my code.

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Settings settings = e.Argument as Settings;
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;


            if ((worker.CancellationPending))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;

            }
            else
            {

                if (settings.O1_Enabled)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        counter_O1 = Convert.ToInt32(this.rowcount_O1.Text);
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, but don't get any type of warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It is not legal.
You can't access UI in background worker like this. To do so You need to invoke this, for example:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                counter_O1 = Convert.ToInt32(this.rowcount_O1.Text);
            }));
```

Comment: btw. It is some operation so performance will be affected, but in the way You don't have to worry about :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, appreciate it!

Comment: Always pleasure to help.